# Getting Access denied on 'db\txn-current-lock' on commit SVN on Windows

Tags: svn, windows-7, windows-xp, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I am running VisualSVNServer on a remote server (Server 2007 R2) and Tortoise SVN 1.6.12 x64 on my Windows 7 machine. I have set up a repository on the server and am able to rep-browse to it and checkout. When I add files (which it lets me do) and then commit, I get the following error

Can't open file 'C:\Repositories\Test\db\txn-current-lock': Access is denied

I have set up read/write permissions from within VisualSVNServer and gave my user id Full Control over the repositories directory. I have read on how to fix this in Linux, but I am running Windows 7. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 18):

You need to assign **Read / Write** permissions on `C:\Repositories\Test\` (recursive) for the user account, under which your server runs ('Network Service' by default).

(In the Windows Explorer go to "C:\Repositories" then Right-click on "Test" folder | **Properties** | **Permissions** tab).

See the Knowledge Base article ["Permissions required to run VisualSVN Server"](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00037/).

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem on Windows XP SP3.
The VisualSVN Server service "Log On As" needs to be Local System, NOT Local Service.

(Right-click My Computer -> Manage -> Services and Applications -> Services -> double click VisualSVN Server -> Log On -> select Local System account, then restart the service)

Comment: I had to change the Windows Service's Log-on to use "local system" as it actually selected Network Service which allowed read and traverse but not committing. Once i made this change to both the Visual SVN service and the background service and restarted them I was able to successfully commit changes. We are using Windows Server 2012 R2

Answer (score 1):

`Can't open file 'D:\Repositories\learning\txn-current-lock': Access is denied`

In the Windows Explorer go to `D:\Repositories` where your repository is located then right-click on `Repositories` folder then `Properties` then `Edit Permissions` tab and allow all full control to everyone.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got this solved by adding full permissions to [NETWORK SERVICE] user for Repositories folder

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue after using SVN for over an year. The solution that worked for us was restarting the SVN service in the server machine.
Hope this helps!